# Managing Cordova/Phonegap app uninstall

Tags: android, cordova

My Cordova app does create some files in the persistent filesystem, and I would like to clean them when the user uninstall the app.

On iOS, as persistent files are stored in the app folder, they will be remove by default, but on Android, they are stored at the device file system root, and they are not removed at uninstall.

Is there any Cordova plugin able to run a script when an app is uninstalled ?

Answer (score 0):

If you create those files in SdCard and all you cannot remove them. But If you create them in AppCache, they will be removed. You cannot manually do some task before uninstalling. OS did not give permission to do that.

Comment: I am afraid that's not clear: do you mean "you can manually do some task before uninstalling" or "you CANNOT manually do some task before uninstalling" ?